# Google Drive/Dropbox like solutions with Offline access and local security and Cross Platform

Tags: android, ios, security, encryption, offline-browsing

Are there any software solutions or SDKs parts that handle the following:

- Propose something like google docs or dropbox, with secured storage for enterprise
- Documents are stored for offline access
- Documents are encrypted
- Solution work on iOS, Android and if possible Windows / Mac OS

I know that google docs will propose offline access and distribute an application on IPad but I would like to know if there are alternatives ?

Thank you

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Nomadesk](https://www.nomadesk.com/) offerings - they do exactly what you need.

Comment: Thanks do you know if this product offers some API i case I want to tweek the interface or create a custom mobile application ? Thanks

Comment: @PhilippeBossu No idea. Did you try to ask Nomadesk support about this? Asking them would be more effective for both you and them.

Answer (score 1):

You can try one of the following cloud services:

1. [Cubby](https://www.cubby.com/video)
2. [Microsoft SkyDive](https://skydrive.live.com/)
3. [Wuala](http://www.wuala.com/)
4. [Sugarsync](https://www.sugarsync.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Amazon has this http://aws.amazon.com/s3/ wich has a great API.